# ApproximateTime policy not working

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ros-kinetic, approximatetime

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
I'm trying to synchronize 2 topic(color/image and semantic_image) but unfortantelly the callback function doesn't work , here is my code ;

```
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/synchronizer.h>
#include <message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Image.h>

using namespace sensor_msgs;
using namespace message_filters;
void callback(const ImageConstPtr& image1, const ImageConstPtr& image2)
 {
   // Solve all of perception here...
   std::cout<<"CallBack works ...";
 }

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "vision_node");

  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  message_filters::Subscriber<Image> image1_sub(nh, "semantic_pcl/semantic_image", 1);
  message_filters::Subscriber<Image> image2_sub(nh, "camera/color/image_raw", 1);

   typedef sync_policies::ApproximateTime<Image, Image> MySyncPolicy;

  // ApproximateTime takes a queue size as its constructor argument, hence MySyncPolicy(10)
  
   Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy> sync(MySyncPolicy(30), image1_sub, image2_sub);
    sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2));
    std::cout<<"Sync Image ..."<<std::endl;

    ros::spin();

    return 0;
    }
```

Here is more details of these 2 topics(when running $ rostopic hz & echo ...) ;

---

Image_raw ;

```
   $ rostopic echo /camera/color/image_raw
 header: 
   seq: 47205
   stamp: 
   secs: 1615561761
   nsecs: 128132582
   frame_id: "camera_color_optical_frame"
   height: 720
   width: 1280
   encoding: "rgb8"
   is_bigendian: 0
   step: 3840 
   data: [131, 146, 132, 132, 147, 133,
```

$ rostopic hz /camera/color/image_raw

```
subscribed to [/camera/color/image_raw]
   average rate: 30.187
min: 0.025s max: 0.044s std dev: 0.00285s window: 28
    average rate: 30.076
    min: 0.025s max: 0.044s std dev: 0.00226s
```

semantic_image :

$ rostopic echo /semantic_pcl/semantic_image

```
header: 
   seq: 18
   stamp: 
   secs: 0
   nsecs:         0
   frame_id: ''
   height: 480
   width: 640
   encoding: "bgr8"  
   is_bigendian: 0
   step: 1920
   data: [128, 192, 64, 128, 192,
```

$ rostopic hz /semantic_pcl/semantic_image

```
subscribed to [/semantic_pcl/semantic_image]
no new messages
no new messages
average rate: 0.386
min: 2.591s max: 2.591s std dev: 0.00000s window: 2
no new messages
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375572/approximatetime-policy-not-working/) by [Ahmad Kheirandish](https://answers.ros.org/users/63135/ahmad-kheirandish/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We see this in your `rostopic echo` output:

> Image_raw ;
>
> ```
>  $ rostopic echo /camera/color/image_raw
> ```

```
 header: 
   seq: 47205
   stamp: 
     secs: 1615561761
     nsecs: 128132582
```

and:

> ```
> $ rostopic echo /semantic_pcl/semantic_image
> ```

```
header: 
   seq: 18
   stamp: 
     secs: 0
     nsecs:         0
```

Notice the values for the `stamp.secs` and `stamp.nsecs` fields.

While `ApproximateTime` allows some *slop* (ie: delta-t between messages which it will still consider to be published at the same time), with the values for `header.stamp` in your messages, there is a difference of about 2021 *years* between the timestamps of your two message streams.

Is the publisher of `/semantic_pcl/semantic_image` correctly populating the `header` of the messages it's publishing?

If it isn't, you need to fix that (either copy the `stamp` of an incoming message it's processing, or set it to some other meaningful value).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-07**:
So, what was the cause?

**Comment by [Ahmad Kheirandish](https://answers.ros.org/users/63135/ahmad-kheirandish/) on 2021-04-09**:
Thanks for your help , as you said  " **stamp.secs** and **stamp.nsecs** fields " were empty and by fixing that issue with the other  color_image topic that has complete header field half of the problem solved.But I also should use the python version of the ApproximateTime policy and add more "slop" value .

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-09**:\

> But I also should use the python version of the ApproximateTime policy

Could you explain why?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-09**:
You seem to have removed your previous post, in which you wrote:

> Because it seems that there is no "delay" attribution for " ApproximateTime Policy in c++"

Aren't methods like [setMaxIntervalDuration(..)](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/message_filters/html/c++/structmessage__filters_1_1sync__policies_1_1ApproximateTime.html#affa6efb4bd69e494c093d2678c72f21b) on the policy the C++ equivalent?

**Comment by [Ahmad Kheirandish](https://answers.ros.org/users/63135/ahmad-kheirandish/) on 2021-04-09**:
Because it seems that for ApproximateTime Policy **"ApproximateTimeSynchronizer in c++"** with refer to this page; http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters doesn't have delay attribution like the one in python which is **"slop"** , so I used the python one.

Here is my code;

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
 from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
 import message_filters 

 rospy.init_node('myimage')
 rate = rospy.Rate(30) # 10hz


 def got_image(sem_image,image_raw):
     sync_sem=sem_image
     print "Got an Semantic_Image and Image_raw"
     pub.publish(sync_sem)

 pub = rospy.Publisher('sync_semantic_image', Image, queue_size=10)
 sem_image_sub = message_filters.Subscriber('/semantic_pcl/semantic_image', Image  )   
raw_camera_sub = message_filters.Subscriber('/camera/color/image_raw', Image )

 ats = message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer([sem_image_sub, raw_camera_sub], queue_size=1 , slop= 8.0)

 ats.registerCallback(
```

**Comment by [Ahmad Kheirandish](https://answers.ros.org/users/63135/ahmad-kheirandish/) on 2021-04-09**:
Yes , you are right , I didn't notice this that somehow  **setMaxIntervalDuration(..)** is equivalent to **slop** in python version , in page; http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters/ApproximateTime it indicates that.